# Listening for raw TCP packets with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I've got some devices (think heart rate monitor) that are going to send raw TCP packets to my Meteor server. When it receives data, it'll write to the mongodb & then I'll use Meteor to publish and invalidate that data to the client.

As I understand it, sockJS can't do raw TCP packets, so I set up a `net` server to receive them. The code works great in pure node, but when I use it with `npmRequire` I get the following error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'startNet' TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createServer'
```

Here's my code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'startNet': function (port) {
    var net = Meteor.npmRequire('net');
    net.createServer(function (socket) {
      console.log("connected");

      socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
      });
    }).listen(port);
  }
});
```

Any ideas why the `net` variable returns an empty object?

Comment: Where is the file containing this method located? FWIW I can't help thinking you'd be better off running this extra server in a separate app. It doesn't exactly align with Meteor's strengths - perhaps you could share your data access logic across the two apps.

Comment: in the server folder...  so you're suggesting 1 pure node app that shares a db with meteor?

Comment: you must be doing something wrong somewhere else. If I drop into a `meteor shell` and run `var net = Meteor.npmRequire('net');`, then the resulting `net` object does have the `createServer` function. So the problem doesn't seem to be with the code seen here.

Comment: TBH I'd use something like `iron:router` to build a REST interface. Then I'd build a _separate_ socket-based server that receives data from the devices and makes REST calls to your Meteor app. Maximum flexibility whilst keeping things clean and encapsulated.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'm curious, why go REST when we have web sockets? I feel like that'd be taking a giant step backwards and the size of the headers would go up substantially, which would introduce latency since I'll be sending new data ~30 times/second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the require out of the method should work:

```
net = Meteor.npmRequire('net');

Meteor.methods({
  'startNet': function (port) {
    net.createServer(function (socket) {
      console.log("connected");
      socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
      });
    }).listen(port);
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I made a new project & just pasted your code into a server file.  Now, I get an `EBADF` error when the server restarts in addition to the usual error when I run the method. However, based on your comment I tried to run a `meteor shell` and I got a `Server unavailable (waiting to reconnect)` error, so I'm wondering if it's a windows or firewall issue. Will update you when I get home to my OSX machine. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Just to eliminate other variables...the only other changes you made were to add `meteorhacks:npm` and add `"net": "1.0.2"` to the `packages.json` file, correct?

Comment: no, I didn't add anything to `packages.json`. `net` is part of the native node.js, you don't need to include it manually.

Comment: that did it! I removed net from the packages.json & everything works great. Weird. Thanks for your help in debugging!